# Grid collection issue after migrating magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, error, migration

I had to upgrade magento 2.3.0 to magento 2.3.4 on the project I am working for.

I had the following issue that I don't really understand :

system.log :

```
[2020-05-26 10:15:46] report.ERROR: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor [] []
[2020-05-26 10:15:49] report.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to Magento\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface or be null, string given, called in /var/www/magento/current/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 [] []
[2020-05-26 10:15:49] report.ERROR: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor [] []
```

Magento\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection is a virtual class defined here :

di.xml :

```
   <virtualType name="Magento\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">magento_rma_grid</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Rma</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns">
                <item name="relation_parent_real_id" xsi:type="string">sales_order.relation_parent_real_id</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="CreditmemoGridAggregator" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns">
                <item name="transaction_id" xsi:type="string">sales_creditmemo.transaction_id</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_view_rma_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Rma\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

I understand there is a bad constructor call but what I had to change ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean the caches with bin/magento cache:clean and then recompile the dependencies with bin/magento setup:di:compile?

Comment: Already done it's not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Run all the commands at least one and check.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this command:

```
rm -r generated/*
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```